# EJB find method and multiple identifiers

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb

I have the following entity bean that contains multiple @Id:

```
@Entity
@Table (name="meta_tables")
public class MetaTableEnt implements Serializable{

    @Id     
    @Column(name="data_ind")
    private Integer dataInd;

    @Id     
    @Column(name="sk")
    private Integer sk;

    // other columns

}
```

and need to implement the find method:

```
MetaTableEnt mte = em.find(MetaTableEnt.class, object);
```

I defined object as follows, however this doesn't work:

```
public class MetaTableKey implements Serializable {
    public int dbInd;
    public int sk;
}

MetaTableKey object = new MetaTableKey();
object.dbInd = dbInd;
object.sk = sk;
```

I get this error message:

`Provided id of the wrong type for class bi.metadata.MetaTableEnt. Expected: class bi.metadata.MetaTableEnt, got class bi.metadata.MetaTableDao$MetaTableKey`

What's wrong with this code?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/IdClass.html. But you'd better avoid composite kays. This is only the first of many difficulties.

Comment: I will use this entity beans as ready only, the difficulties you mention are related to data updates or queries as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define your Entity with an `@EmbeddedId` class.

So your original Entity would have:

```
@Entity
@Table (name="meta_tables")
public class MetaTableEnt implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private MetaTableEntPK pk;

    ... etc
```

and your embeddable class would be:

```
@Embeddable
public class MetaTableEntPK implements Serializable {

    @Column(name="data_ind")
    private Integer dataInd;

    @Column(name="sk")
    private Integer sk;

    public MetaTableEntPK(Integer dataInd, Integer sk) {
        this.dataInd = dataInd;
        this.sk = sk;
    }
}
```

Then your find code would be something like:

```
MetaTableEntPK pk = new MetaTableEntPK(1, 2);
MetaTableEnt mte = em.find(MetaTableEnt.class, pk);
```

NOTE: In JPQL queries, you need to refer to the fields in this PK as `pk.dataInd`, say. For instance, the following query would find all the `MetaTableEnt` objects with a particular `dataInd`:

```
SELECT object(x) FROM MetaTableEnt x WHERE x.pk.dataInd = 1
```

By the way, don't listen to JB Nizet. 130 of our 400-odd Entities use these `@Embeddable` keys and there's nothing particularly difficult about them.